# How can I customize the text of Liferay language bar

Tags: liferay, customization

After I setup liferay, I configured from control panel to set 8 languages which I want to use in my website. But I see that in the language bar, some of the text is in lower case as well as some in upper case, can I change the text to have the same case?

Now is like:

italiano español português Deutsch français

All in lower case except "Deutsch".

Answer (score 1):

Witch locale is current? Did you try to switch locale and is it same casing in all locales?

As a last measure you can create hook and put in it /html/taglib/ui/language/page.jsp and edit code there to produce casing that you like.

See [Hook Wiki](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Portal+Hook+Plugins)